# python string operation to get firstname lastname and dob from a string

Tags: python, string, split

String could be in a number of formats:

1. Alcievski, Kostadin 26:07:1937
2. Alcievski
3. Alcievski, Kostadin, 26:07:1937
4. Alcievski Kostadin 26:07:1937
5. Alcievski 26:07:1937
6. Kostadin 26:07:1937
7. Alcievski,Kostadin 26:07:1937
8. Alcievski,Kostadin26:07:1937
9. Alcievski,Kostadin,26:07:1937
10. Alcievski,Kostadin,26:07:1937 (1)
11. Alcievski,Kostadin,26:07:37
12. Alcievski,Kostadin,26-07-37

Here's what I have so far:

```
            patient_first_name = patient.split(' ')[1]
            if patient_first_name == ',':
                patient_first_name = patient.split(',')[1]

            if not patient_first_name or ":" in patient_first_name:
                patient_first_name = ''


           patient_last_name = patient.rpartition(',')[0]

           if not  patient_last_name:
                patient_last_name = patient.split(' ')[0]


       split_pat = patient.rpartition(' ')
        patient_dob = split_pat[len(split_pat) - 1]
        patient_dob_string = datetime.strptime(patient_dob, '%d:%m:%Y')
```

But ofcourse it does not work for all the formats. How can I modify this code to give me `fname`, `lname` and `dob` with all such varitations.

Comment: case 5 and 6 are identical. You can't decide if Kostadin/Alcievski is the lastname or firstname without more information. So one will be wrong and the other will be right.

Comment: If there is one string other than dob, will consider it fname. That's okay @Boendal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example from me. Covers the listed in the requirements and other possible cases I can imagine :)

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

sources = [
    'Alcievski, Kostadin 26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski',
    'Alcievski, Kostadin, 26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski Kostadin 26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski 26:07:1937',
    'Kostadin 26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski,Kostadin 26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski,Kostadin26:07:1937',
    'Alcievski,Kostadin,26:07:1937',
]

data = []
for item in sources:
    m = re.match('(.*?)(\d+:\d+:\d+)', item)
    if not m:
        continue

    dob = m.group(2)

    names = m.group(1).strip(' ,')
    names = re.split('[\s,]+', names)

    data.append((names.pop(0), next(iter(names), None), dob))

pprint(data)
```

Outputs

```
# > python test.py
[('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', None, '26:07:1937'),
 ('Kostadin', None, '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937'),
 ('Alcievski', 'Kostadin', '26:07:1937')]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if 'Alcievski, Kostadin, 26:07:1937 (1)'

Comment: It will pass the regex but `(1)` will be skipped since it is not a part of the date/time string expected

Comment: great. Also what if Alcievski,Kostadin,26:07:37 or
Alcievski,Kostadin,26-07-37

Comment: These cases are not covered since not listed in the requirements, but it could be updated easy to the mask which supports just any "-:" between numbers

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

patient = "Alcievski,Kostadin26:07:1937"

# Assuming that first name and last name only contains alphabets
names = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", patient)

if len(names) > 0:
    patient_first_name = names[0]
    if len(names) > 1:
        patient_last_name = names[1]

# Assuming that date format is always %d:%m:%Y
date_format = re.findall("\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\d\d", patient)
if len(date_format) > 0: 
    patient_dob_string = date_format[0]
```

Comment: First and Lastname can at times have special characters like "-" and space

Comment: @Simrankaur Then you can easily add them to accepting characters in the regular expression

Comment: @aminrd but space is also a delimiter for first and lastname